# Include shortcode in custom function

Tags: wordpress, function, shortcode

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function sc_link_grabber() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($post->post_content);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $classes = explode(' ', $link->getAttribute('class'));

        if (in_array('fap-single-track', $classes)) {
            $sc_link = $link->getAttribute( 'href' );
            return $sc_link;
        } 
    }
}
```

However, this was used for stratus in which I would add a song in my posts as:

```
<a href='link goes here' class = "stratus"> title </a>
```

This would extract the link through the class and place a play button on the image. Clicking on the play button would play the song on the player. 
However, I am now using a player called the fullwidth audio player which is instead programmed to use shortcodes. Example of shortcode:

```
[fap_track url="url goes here" title="somethingf" title="somethingf" share_link="" cover="" meta="" layout="list" enqueue="no" auto_enqueue="no"]
```

What I want is to change the function so that it somehow detects the shortcode instead.

Comment: i guess you are looking for `do_shortcode` wp function

Answer (score 0):

you can use do_shortcode to do the trick:

```
do_shortcode('[fap_track url="url goes here" title="somethingf" title="somethingf" share_link="" cover="" meta="" layout="list" enqueue="no" auto_enqueue="no"]');
```

hope this helps..